# Sorting a csv file in Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am attempting to sort my csv file by a specific column. That is easy enough with this below code:

```
with open("outfile.csv","rb") as infile,open("outfile.csv","wb") as outfile:
    reader= csv.reader(infile,delimiter=',')
    writer= csv.writer(outfile)
    sort= sorted(reader,key=operator.itemgetter(7), reverse= True)
    for eachline in sort:
        writer.writerow(eachline)
```

In my example however, it will sort but will sort in an odd way. For example, it would return the file to me descending in this order: 3.8,3.7,3.1,21.7,21.6,2.8.

Since this is causing me an issue, I would like to fix this; if it can't, instead I'd like to sort by largest length if that is possible.

This sounds confusing but this is the issue I am having. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like alphabetical order, you may need to consider how you cast it to float for the sorting, assuming you want numerical order, e.g. `key=lambda x: float(x[7])`

Comment: My issue now is that I have the header first, thus making it a string at runtime when I need it to be a float.

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting `float` values instead of `str` values:

```
sort= sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x[7]), reverse= True)
```

Comment: My issue now is that I have the header first, thus making it a string at runtime when I need it to be a float

Comment: If you have a header in your input, try reading it singly, storing it in some variable, then sorting the remaining lines. When you write the result, write the header first and then write the sorted result.